# Precomputed Eigenfaces

Tags: data-request, images, faces

I know how to compute eigenfaces from a faces dataset, but before doing it, I'd like to know if there is some precomputed eigenfaces dataset.

So, instead of downloading thousands of faces (for instance, from the [FERET](http://www.itl.nist.gov/iad/humanid/feret/feret_master.html) dataset or the [LWF](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/) dataset) and applying eigendecomposition, I could get some (say, the top 100) eigenfaces (+ average face) directly, like the image below.

For now, I don't care from which dataset they are extracted. Also, my goal is to generate random faces from linear combinations of eigenfaces, not to do face recognition.

[image]